# Cómo puedo utilizar PHP JavaBridge

Tags: php, java, tomcat, apache2

buen día, me gustaría saber todos los pasos para utilizar e implementar PHP/JavaBridge, ya que necesito ejecutar código Java desde una página en PHP, si pudieran apoyarme con tutoriales o bien de alguien que ya haya implementado algo parecido, de antemano gracias

Saludos cordiales

Comment: Tu pregunta es bastante general. En la pagina de JavaBridge vienen ejemplos de uso aunque podrían no concordar con la aplicación Java a la que te quieres conectar o el caso de uso que pretendes trabajar. Lo que a mi parecer deberías hacer es intentar la implementación por cuenta propia y donde te atores poner tu pregunta puntual con lo que no hace o el error que se te presenta.

Comment: Entiendo, trataré por todos los medios ver en qué punto me quedo atorado, para volver a realizar la pregunta debidamente, saludos cordiales